# merge data from rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

I have a source table like so:

```
id | code | description | parent_code | level
1    111     testone      null           1
2    222     testtwo      null           1
3    333     testthree    111            2
4    444     testfour     222            2
```

Which I will have to upload to a new table with the result like so:

```
id | codelevel1 | descriptionlevel1 | codeleve2 | descriptionlevel2
1    111          testone              333        testthree
2    222          testtwo              444        testfour
```

Please note I have a total of 6 levels, so in the target table, I have ...CodeLevel6 DescriptionLevel6 as the last two columns

I investigated the use of WITH AS recursive queries, but am currently stuck on how the codelevel1...codelevel6 fields will be filled in for a unique existing ID.

Comment: i think you are searching for PIVOT : https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a hierarchical query to get all rows with the same root element and then use PIVOT to transform the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS root_id, code, description, lvl
  FROM t
  CONNECT BY parent_code = PRIOR code
  START WITH parent_code IS NULL
)
PIVOT
(
  MIN(code) AS code, MIN(description) AS description
  FOR lvl IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
)
```

With `lvl IN ( 1, 2 )` this returns:

```
   ROOT_ID     1_CODE 1_DESCRIPTION     2_CODE 2_DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------- ------------- ---------- -------------
         1        111 testone              333 testthree    
         2        222 testtwo              444 testfour
```